# Generating a list based on a list of dictionaries and data from another list

Tags: python, list

The following lists are given:

```
atr = [{'name': 'surname', 'type': 'varchar(50)', 'table': None}, {'name': 'ls_data', 'type': 'timestamp', 'table': None}, {'name': 'cpn', 'type': 'int', 'table': None}, {'name': 'code', 'type': 'varchar(200)', 'table': None}]

 pk = ['surname', 'cpn', 'ls_data']
```

It is necessary to form a list of "type" from the atr list, while "name" from atr = pk.
The order should be as in the pk list.

**Expected output**

```
lst = ['varchar(50)', 'int', 'timestamp']
```

I tried it like this

```
lst = [d["type"] for d in atr if d["name"] in pk]
```

But this is incorrect, the order is not the same as in the pk list.

Comment: `[j['type'] for i in pk for j in atr if i == j['name']]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It would work using something like this:

```
lst = [atr[[d["name"] for d in atr].index(p)]["type"] for p in pk]
```

The output for print(lst) is:

```
['varchar(50)', 'int', 'timestamp']
```

i.e. the same result items list order as in the query items list as opposed to your original approach which gives a different order.

Though I'm not sure how readable/performant that is; it

1. **generates** a **new list** (only containing the values of the "name" key) from the list of dictionaries for each query item p in pk
2. **searches for the index** of the current query item p in that list
3. uses this index to **retrieve** the respective **dictionary** from the original atr list
4. and finally, select the value of the "type" key from that dictionary